# Binding to an output component without EventEmitter. is it possible?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a set of component, and I have found quite easy to make property binding when it comes to input, there are several options (e.g., input()). But for output of a component, I have found it complicate, just one option using output(). The way I know you must create an EventEmitter, and the components interested on the output must subscribe. Is there an easier way?

It would be amazing something that does not require subscription and EventEmitter, I guess.

Here goes a sample of what I am talking about:

```
export class PriceQuoterComponent {
  @Output() lastPrice = new EventEmitter<PriceQuote>();

  priceQuote: PriceQuote;

  constructor() {
    interval(2000)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.priceQuote = {
          stockSymbol: 'IBM',
          lastPrice: 100 * Math.random()
        };

        this.lastPrice.emit(this.priceQuote);})


}
```

Comment: Looks pretty simple to me!

Comment: It is error prone. I have tried to do it several times, and it is error prone.

Comment: Error prone in what way? Human error?

Comment: Furthermore, it bothers me this interval emitting from second to seconds.

Comment: The rxjs interval is nothing to do with EventEmitter though? Do you have an issue with interval or EventEmitter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend it but you could also provide a function via an input and call it on each change:

```
export class PriceQuoterComponent {
  @Input() lastPrice: Function<Number>;

  priceQuote: PriceQuote;

  constructor() {
    interval(2000)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.priceQuote = {
          stockSymbol: 'IBM',
          lastPrice: 100 * Math.random()
        };

        if (this.lastPrice) {
          this.lastPrice(this.priceQuote);
        }
   })
}
```